# does anyone know how to do this css transition?

Tags: css, css-transitions

I am killing my neurons trying to figure out how to do this website's navigation bar with css transitions or animations: http://tabu.realitatea.net/ .

Does anybody know how to do it ? or even give me a starting point ?

Comment: You'd pull this off with a scroll event and a class change with something like jQuery. Looks like it's adding a property to the navbar once the page gets to a certain scroll depth to stick it to the top.

Comment: He's not talking about the fixed header imo. Try mousing over the nav, he's talking about the red div that slides around.

Comment: @James Ives i ment when you hover on the navigation bar there is a red thing that moves.

Comment: My bad, the magic is happening in this div, try moving the left and width properties around and you can see how it pushes the background across the navbar container: "<div class="gdlr-navigation-gimmick" id="gdlr-navigation-gimmick" style="left: 800px; width: 50px; overflow: hidden;"></div>".  If you look in the sites javascript under the gdlr-script.js file and look for the slide_nav variable it will hold the key to your question. Hope that helps!

Comment: @Urarii Please edit your question to include this clarification there, in the question body, not in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was pretty fun to make, check it out. https://jsfiddle.net/6brsm2zt/

JS

```
var slider = $('#slider');

$('div').on('mouseenter','a',function(){
  var box = $(this);
  var p = box.position();
  slider.animate({
    width: box.outerWidth(),
    left: p.left,
  },250);
})

$('div').on('mouseleave','a',function(){
  slider.stop();
})

$('div').on('mouseleave',function(){
  $('#slider').animate({
    width: 0,
    left: 0,
  },200);
})
```

The basic idea is to have a zero width div on the left, let's call it a slider. When you mouse over an item, you set the width and left position of the slider to be equal to the width and left position of the item. The duration of the animation is quite short, about a third of a second, to give the feeling of responsiveness.

When you mouse off the bar entirely, just set the width and left position of the slider to 0 with a short duration, say 200 ms, and it'll zoom off to the side.

One tricky part is when you wave the mouse back and forth. Originally, the div would play the transition for each item, leaving me waiting for the slider to finally come to my mouse. I solved this by cancelling the animation when i mouse off an item. Since the event order for mousing between items is mouseenter -> mouseleave -> mouseenter, i already had a transition for mouseenter ready to go. Now the slider will chase your mouse relentlessly :D.

Comment: Thanks man, you are a genious!